# Deleting all the subfolders having fewer than X files

Tags: bash, terminal, find

I would like to remove all the subfolders having less than X file in a folder

The following code search those subfolders with less than X file:

```
$ find . -type d -exec sh -c 'set -- "$0"/*; [ $# -le 10 ]' {} \; -print
./digna_1919
./digna_2040
./digna_1682
(more output omitted)
```

So I can find them! But if I do this, I get "Directory not empty":

```
$ find . -type d -exec sh -c 'set -- "$0"/*; [ $# -le 10 ]' {} \; -delete
find: cannot delete ‘./digna_1919’: Directory not empty
find: cannot delete ‘./digna_2040’: Directory not empty
find: cannot delete ‘./digna_1682’: Directory not empty
(more output omitted)
```

And if I do this, I get "No such file or directory":

```
$ find . -type d -exec sh -c 'set -- "$0"/*; [ $# -le 10 ]' {} \; -exec rm -r "{}" \;
find: ‘./digna_1919’: No such file or directory
find: ‘./digna_2040’: No such file or directory
find: ‘./digna_1682’: No such file or directory
(more output omitted)
```

Where am I doing wrong? Thanks a lot!

[Source of the code](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89925/how-to-delete-directories-based-on-find-output)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `-depth` to have `find` process each directory's contents before the directory itself. You'll want to do this any time you delete items.

```
$ find . -depth -type d -exec sh -c 'set -- "$0"/*; [ $# -le 10 ]' {} \; -exec rm -r {} \;
```

Comment: Using `-print` instead of `-exec rm` had as first outputs the folders names. This is why I'm surprised that your code worked perfectly :P Thanks you very much!

Comment: Right -- you want the folder names to be *last*.

Comment: But using -print the folder names were not the last, this is what surprise me. It's not relevant to the question tho